# jetty:run-exploded updating static resources

Tags: maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm running a maven project which has a war dependency. I have a couple of resources specific to the actual project which is located in *src/main/webapp*.

When I start developing the project using `mvn jetty:run-exploded`, the project gets assembled in *target/* with its overlay applied.

When running Linux, if I update resources in *src/main/webapp* - within seconds the update is applied to its target directory as well. However, on Windows, the target is never updated until I stop and rerun maven. I've applied a custom *webdefault.xml* for jetty to disable jetty's file-locking.

Anyone has this kind of setup working on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

JRebel can do what you want. Not sure of a native Maven way to achieve this. See the [JRebel configuration docs](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html) for more info if you're interested.